# Range as a Variable VBA

Tags: vba, variables, range

I am trying to copy  values from sheet1 to sheet2. The number of rows of sheet1 varies so I need to store it in a variable. I need something like:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:Ab").Select
```

, where "b" is a variable that stores the number of rows in Sheet1.

Thank you.

Comment: `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & b).Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually store the `UsedRange` of a worksheet. Or just copy to another sheet directly. e.g.

```
Set oWS1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set oWS2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
oWS2.UsedRange.Clear ' Clear used range in Sheet2
oWS1.UsedRange.Copy oWS2.Range("A1") ' Copies used range of Sheet1 to A1 of Sheet2

'Set oRng = oWS1.UsedRange ' Sets a Range reference to UsedRange of Sheet1
```

To get the last row of a sheet:

```
lLastRow = oWS1.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
```

EDIT (Getting Last Row from UsedRange's Address):

```
Dim sAddr as String, lLastRow As Long
sAddr = oWS1.UsedRange.Address
lLastRow = CLng(Mid(sAddr, InStrRev(sAddr , "$") + 1))
```

Comment: + 1 :) However, just a heads up. `UsedRange` should never be used to find the last row which has data. You may want to see [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba). Here it is fine since you are just copying from one sheet to other but if the user wanted to write to the last row then `UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row` might give you unexpected results :)

Comment: Thanks @SiddharthRout, i didn't thought that method will change when the last row is hidden! Your solution works even all the rows are hidden! Alternatively, I think I can make use of the Address of the UsedRange...

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to dynamically create the cell name by concatenating your column and row identifiers and then using the Range(Cell1,Cell2) overload, as below:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim intStart As Integer
Dim intEnd As Integer
Dim strStart As String
Dim strEnd As String

'Let's say your range is A2 to A10
intStart = 2
intEnd = 10
strStart = "A" & intStart
strEnd = "A" & intEnd

Set x = Range(strStart, strEnd)
```

Comment: When working with rows in Excel, it is advisable that you do not declare them as `Integers` but as `Long`. To test it, change `intEnd = 10` to `intEnd = 1048570` :)

Comment: @Siddharth - Thanks! This was a rushed and somewhat haphazard POC, but I'll keep this in mind!

Comment: I always use the type from MS Object References, when I am not sure, I use `?typename(...)` in Immediate window, e.g. `?typename(range("a1").row)` gives Long, you might be surprised that most numeric constants are Long in Excel - `?typename(xllastcell)` gives `Long`.